# Mini-git class performance issue

Tags: c#, performance, hash-map

I want to build Git class where i can store integers. `FilesSet` is where I store current state of integers. `Commits`' key is basically commit number so I can checkout pretty fast. `Hashes` is used for quick search of hashes that I need in commit part.

`Update` is for updating current state of integers.

In `Commit` I want to save a copy of current state and do it fast. First of all I don't want to compare arrays of integers, so I calculate hash of current state. Then if `Hashes` already has that hash as a key, I add to `Commits` Pair of commitNumber and  integer array that corresponds to that hash so I won't have to store another copy of array. And in `Hashes` of this key I add commit Number so I can see which commits have that hash. This one is a bottleneck for my solution.

In `Checkout` I basically get int that I need by arguments. I think this method is already really fast. 
I need this class to be fast but I can't really provide test cases as they are hidden at my college testing system. My current solution is too slow with `int Commit()` . 
Here it is :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

namespace GitTask
{
    public class Git
    {
        int[] FilesSet { get; set; }
        Dictionary<int, int[]> Commits { get; set; }
        SortedList<int, List<int>> Hashes { get; set; }

        public Git(int filesCount)
        {
            FilesSet = new int[filesCount];
            Commits = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
            Hashes = new SortedList<int, List<int>>();
        }

        public void Update(int fileNumber, int value)
        {
            FilesSet[fileNumber] = value;
        }

        public int Commit()
        {
            var commitNumber = Commits.Count;
            var tempHash = GetMyHashCode(FilesSet);

            if (Hashes.TryGetValue(tempHash, out List<int> key))
            {
                Commits.Add(commitNumber, Commits[key[0]]);
                Hashes[tempHash].Add(commitNumber);
                return commitNumber;
            }
            Commits.Add(Commits.Count, FilesSet.Clone() as int[]);
            Hashes.Add(tempHash, new List<int>(new int[] { commitNumber }));
            return commitNumber;
        }

        public int Checkout(int commitNumber, int fileNumber)
        {
            if (commitNumber >= Commits.Count)
                throw new ArgumentException();
            else
            {
                var commit = Commits[commitNumber];
                return commit[fileNumber];
            }
        }

        private int GetMyHashCode(int[] array)
        {
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
            {
                result = unchecked(result * 31 + array[i]);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect you to come up with tips on speeding it up or creating new kind of storing files. I also tried to measure performance of methods and it seems like calculating hash of big array is a problem and adding to `SortedList<int,List<int>>` is a problem as well.

Comment: What I would recommend is to try to space it more (use paragraphs) :)

Comment: How much of the API is imposed by the spec and how much is amenable to suggestions for redesign?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Other than the performance is too slow are there any other issues? Does the code work as expected?

Comment: @pacmaninbw there's no other problems rather than speed. Code works correct to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Hash code collisions

There's a problem with `Commit`: matching hash codes do not mean that two objects are equal ('pigeonhole principle'). For example, both `[1, 0]` and `[0, 31]` have hash code 31. You can only be sure that objects are not equal when their hash codes don't match - the inverse is not true.

Also, are you sure that reusing arrays is worth the effort? If `filesCount` is small, then the savings are small as well, and if `filesCount` is large, then the likelyhood that a specific state has occurred before is probably very small.

#### Multiple smaller arrays

One alternative is to divide the state into multiple smaller arrays. This limits the impact of individual changes: you only need to copy a 'sub-array' (and create a new 'array-of-arrays'), instead of copying the full state. This also increases the likelyhood that a particular sub-array has occurred before, although I do not think that is something you need to be concerned about.

In Git terms, this is similar to using multiple files instead of a single large file. Committing changes to a single file only creates a new blob for the modified file and a new tree object that references the new blob (and older blobs for unmodified files).

#### Change-sets

Another alternative is to store a change-set for each value, using a binary search to find the value for a particular commit number. This can save a lot of space, but it'll make checkouts slower. Whether that trade-off is worth it depends on the intended use of this class.

#### Other notes

- Instead of `Clone() as int[]`, you can use Linq's `ToArray()` method.
- I'd put the last 4 lines of `Commit` inside an `else` statement, to make it clearer that these are two mutually exclusive paths.
- On the other hand, I would not use an `else` statement in `Checkout` - the `if` check is an 'early-out' guard clause, not a full-blown separate path.
- In `Checkout`, an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` might be better suited. You may also want to guard against negative values. And why not check for invalid file numbers as well?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>        if (Hashes.TryGetValue(tempHash, out List<int> key))
>        {
>            Commits.Add(commitNumber, Commits[key[0]]);
>            Hashes[tempHash].Add(commitNumber);
> ```

Be consistent: you've already got an alias for `Hashes[tempHash]`, so use it.

Also, on the subject of names, why `tempHash` instead of just `hash`? And `key` for the value of a `KeyValuePair` is a tad confusing.

---

> I also tried to measure performance of methods and it seems like calculating hash of big array is a problem and adding to `SortedList<int,List<int>>` is a problem as well.

Well done for profiling. Both of those problems seem to me to have the same solution: don't do it.

The hash can be updated incrementally. FWIW, real solutions do this using a Merkle tree. To make this robust you need to do something about the `FilesSet` property. You should only expose the data in read-only form (e.g. as `IReadOnlyList<int>`), and if you have a setter it should take a defensive copy and recalculate the hash from scratch. But I'd be strongly tempted to remove the property and the `Update` method and replace them with an indexer.

As to the second: why use `SortedList`? What advantage does it give here over a `Dictionary`?

Aside from those points, I think the design is back to front. It would be simpler to do things the way version control systems actually do it: the commit version (tag) references the hash, and the hash references the data.